# Convert all element names to lower case with XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

In XSL, how does one convert all element names in a document to lower case before processing it? We're using XSLT 2.0, and we've tried the following but it does not work...

```
<A>
  <ITEMS>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
  </ITEMS>
</A>


<xsl:transform>

  <xsl:template match="*">      
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>     

//do work here...  
<xsl:apply-templates>
  ...

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get any output at all?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I get output, yes, but the case it not changed; the output XML is an exact copy of the input XML.

Comment: Just to clarify further, you're trying to change the case of the elements *before* processing with the other templates, correct? So you would match "items" and not "ITEMS", right?

Comment: yes, and the entire doc, see answer from Lukasz below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works under Altova XMLSpy:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xsl:output exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">      
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <ITEMS>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
  </ITEMS>
</A>
```

XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <items>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </items>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Comment: No reason to use `translate()` when the OP is using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Right. For some reason I read that they were not using Xslt 2.0.