# How can I make all XML tags lowercase in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm parsing some XML that I get from various feeds. Apparently some of the XML has an occasional tag that is all upper case. I'd like to normalize the XML to be all lower case tags to make searching, etc. easier.

What I want to do is something like:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_content)
node = parsed.css("title")  # => should return a Nokogiri node for the title tag
```

However, some of the XML documents have "TITLE" for that tag.

What are my options for getting that node whether it's tag is "title", "TITLE", or even "Title"?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279513/how-can-i-create-a-nokogiri-case-insensitive-xpath-selector) seems to address this directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267973/convert-all-element-names-to-lower-case-with-xsl

Comment: Possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2279611/244128

Comment: Yeah, that's a little more complicated than I hoped. I wish it could have been as simple as: `node = parsed.at_css("title", :insensitive => true)` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transform your xml document by downcase'ing all tag names, here's one way to do it:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_content)
parsed.traverse do |node|
  node.name = node.name.downcase if node.kind_of?(Nokogiri::XML::Element)
end
```

Comment: It appears that this doesn't work because the nodes in the block are also children nodes, which are Nokogiri::XML::Text and don't have node_name. I.e.:


`2.2.0 :075 > parsed.traverse {|node| node.node_name = node.node_name.downcase unless node.node_name == "document" }
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
  from (irb):75:in `block in irb_binding'`

Comment: However, this appears to work: `parsed.traverse {|node| node.name = node.name.downcase if node.class == Nokogiri::XML::Element }`

Comment: My only follow-on question is: will tags always be Nokogiri::XML::Elements or do I need to check for other options?

Comment: @DanSharp: yes, "tags" are formally known as "elements" - this is a great solution.

Comment: Is there a difference between `node.node_name` and `node.name`?

Comment: @DanSharp: it looks like `node_name` is equivalent to `node`.

Comment: Yup. Just found the line in the Nokogiri source: `alias :name           :node_name`

Comment: thanks for the edits @maerics, I've edited again slightly to use the XML::Element logic the hive mind came up with, but in my opinion better code style on one line.

Comment: Thank you both!   This solved it for me! The traverse call is fast and lets me pre-process the XML data in Nokogiri, thus allowing my future searches via css("something") to work and remain elegant (I didn't want to do custom xpaths)

Comment: @jrochkind  I agree. In fact, I'd possibly even put the traverse block on one line. I like the kind_of? call even better than class ==

Comment: Interesting note: you cannot chain `traverse` with the `parse()` method. You have to parse the XML first into a variable, then traverse that variable.

Comment: It's not that you can't do it in one line, but that you'll lose access to your actual Nokogiri::Document object, since traverse does not return it. You could probably do something fancy with `tap` if you have ActiveSupport, but two lines is reasonable. (Or a PR to nokogiri to make traverse return the caller instead of nil!)

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach you could transform all element (tag) names to lower case (e.g. by using XSLT or another solution) and then do all of your XPath/CSS queries using lower case only.

[This XSLT solution should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268269/244128); however, my version of Ruby (2.0.0p481) and/or Nokogiri (1.5.6) complains mysteriously (perhaps about the use of the "`lower-case(...)`" function? Perhaps Nokogiri doesn't support XSLT v2?)

Here's a solution that seems to work:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('lower.xslt'))
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
#   <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
#   <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
#   <xsl:template match="*">
#     <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
#       <xsl:apply-templates />
#     </xsl:element>
#   </xsl:template>
# </xsl:transform>

doc  = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('doc.xml'))
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <FOO>
#  <BAR>Bar</BAR>
#  <GAH>Gah</GAH>
#  <ZIP><DOO><DAH/></DOO></ZIP>
# </FOO>

puts xslt.transform(doc)
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <foo>
#   <bar>Bar</bar>
#   <gah>Gah</gah>
#   <zip><doo><dah/></doo></zip>
# </foo>
```

Comment: This works, but it removes any additional attributes on any tags. So if I have:  `<BAR stuff="whatever">Bar</BAR>`  it becomes: `<bar>Bar</bar>` and I lose the `stuff="whatever"`.  That may not matter for my specific needs (I need to make sure the tags don't have attributes).

Comment: @DanSharp: ah, good observation, I didn't think to check that =(